# Creation of non-root user in multi-stage Dockerfile

Tags: azure, docker, alpine-linux

i've been trying to create a non-root user because it's a good practice and it can solve a Twistlock compliance vulnerability.

This is the Dockerfile where i have to create the non-root user:

```
# Build
FROM node:12-alpine AS build
USER root

# Upgrade the system
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add git && apk add openssh-client && apk add bash && apk add openjdk8 && apk add chromium && mkdir /root/.ssh
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

# Set the credentials to download the libraries
COPY credentials/known_hosts /root/.ssh/known_hosts
COPY credentials/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
COPY credentials/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa


# Add chromium for the unit tests
RUN \
  echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && apk --no-cache  update \
  && apk --no-cache  upgrade \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gifsicle pngquant optipng libjpeg-turbo-utils \
    udev ttf-opensans chromium \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /tmp/*

ENV CHROME_BIN /usr/bin/chromium-browser
ENV LIGHTHOUSE_CHROMIUM_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser


# set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

# copy the code into the image and download all the required libraries
COPY . .
RUN npm ci --unsafe-perm

# run unit tests
RUN npm run test:ci
# package the solution
RUN npm run build:prod

# Webserver
FROM nginx:1.17.10-alpine
USER root

# Upgrade the system
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add bash

# copy the configuration for nginx
COPY /src/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY /src/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

# delete the previous content
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*


COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/myapp /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --chown=root:root --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/myapp/config.json /usr/share/nginx/html/config.json
RUN chmod u=root:root /usr/share/nginx/html/config.json
COPY --chown=root:root entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/.scannerwork /usr/.scannerwork
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And i tried the commands:

```
RUN adduser -S appuser
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
USER appuser
```

This is the error that i get:

[Error-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeUuM.png)

I need some help here.

Sorry for my bad english and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you created `asouser` but used `appuser` instead, am I missing something?

Comment: That was just an error of the copypaste, but i tried it when it was appuser in both places and it didn't work either

Comment: It prints out the string `Error-Image`, and nothing more?  Can you show the code that produces it?  (Is there text output, and do you need to replace that link with the actual text of the error?)

Comment: Error-Image is a link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeUuM.png

Comment: Can you share the complete Dockerfile and command-line commands you're using?